# chrome headless (--headless=new) is also used to set the desired window size ("--window-size=1920,1080")

Tags: user-interface, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

With the new update in Chrome browser, the headless has been renewed, it does not work with old codes. After the Headless is renewed, the windows size feature does not work directly. You can make it work with the codes below.

work to add this code ("force-device-scale-factor=0,5"),

worked for "--headless=new"

```
  WebDriver driver; /* start driver*/
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
  options.addArguments("--headless=new");                         
  options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
  options.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0,5");
  driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.